# Running py.test under pypy

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pypy

How do I run pytest using pypy? Travis does it, so it must be possible. This is related to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928317/running-py-test-on-micropython) how to run pytest using Micropython.

```
arkadiusz@pc:~/Dokumenty/GitHub/construct$ pypy -m pytest
/usr/bin/pypy: No module named pytest
```

Comment: http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: You'll need to install it for/with your pypy interpreter (e.g. using `pypy -m pip install pytest`)

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/834466/installing-pytest-for-pypy?noredirect=1#comment1274310_834466 @TheCompiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed by installing pip on pypy as in

https://askubuntu.com/questions/834466/installing-pytest-for-pypy

Then it is just

```
pypy -m pytest
```

Comment: Hey @ArekBulski Did you have any luck on getting pytest running on micropython?